# Quickest way to count the number of nonzero elements in the output of get_weights()

Tags: numpy, keras, neural-network

I would like to calculate the number of nonzero values in the weights of a neural network.

I tried the following code, but I obtained a ValueError. This may be due to the reason that each array has different shape.

```
h = model.get_weights()  # return a list of numpy arrays
merged_h = []
for l in h:
    merged_h += l
nzcounts = np.count_nonzero(merged_h)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (3,3,3,32)
```

I wonder if there are other ways to compute the number of nonzero elements in the output of `get_weights()`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that `model.get_weights()` returns a list of arrays. I think the easiest way to do that is to apply `np.count_nonzero()` to each one of those arrays independently and then sum the results.

```py
np.sum([np.count_nonzero(x) for x in model.get_weights()])
```